# is it possible to convert this reject to rails active record query?

Tags: mysql

Right now I am getting the dealings by dealings.all and do the below reject statement , but is there a way that I can just query this in just one go ? I have a few ruby codes like pluck and max and I am just wondering if I can mix ruby code in sql code.

> dealings.reject {|n|
>
> (n.item_rank == :import && n.dealings.pluck(:status).max == Contract::import) ||
>       (n.item_rank == :process && n.dealings.pluck(:status).max == Contract::process) ||
>       (n.item_rank == :export && n.dealings.pluck(:status).max == Contract::export)
>     }
>
> end

Comment: Most probably it is possible, but to get some real help with the query it's better to provide the schema and the example of the data in `negotiations` and `deal_buildings`...

Comment: Do not edit your questions so drastically, just create new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is possible using sub-query. Here is a raw sql example:

```rb
negotiations = Negotiation.from('(select negotiations.*, (select max(status) from deal_buildings where deal_buildings.deal_id = negotiations.id) max_status from negotiations) negotiations')
negotiations = negotiations.where(business_rank: [17, 19, 22])
negotiations = negotiations.where(main_member_id: 7)
negotiations = negotiations.where(
  '((business_rank = ? and max_status = ?) or (business_rank = ? and max_status = ?) or (business_rank = ? and max_status = ?)) is false',
  'application', Supplier::Building::STATUS_APPLY,
  'agreement', Supplier::Building::STATUS_CONTRACT,
  'settlement', Supplier::Building::STATUS_SETTLEMENT
)
```

And [query object](https://medium.flatstack.com/query-object-in-ruby-on-rails-56ea434365f0):

```rb
class NegotiationsQuery
  def all
    Negotiation.from(negotiations_and_max_status_query)
  end

  private

  def negotiations
    @negotiations ||= Arel::Table.new(:negotiations)
  end

  def deal_buildings
    @deal_buildings ||= Arel::Table.new(:deal_buildings)
  end

  def max_status_query
    deal_buildings.project(deal_buildings[:status].maximum).where(
      deal_buildings[:deal_id].eq(negotiations[:id])
    ).as('max_status')
  end

  def negotiations_and_max_status_query
    negotiations.project(negotiations[Arel.star], max_status_query).as('negotiations')
  end
end
```

```rb
  negotiations = NegotiationsQuery.new.all
  negotiations = negotiations.where(business_rank: [17, 19, 22])
  negotiations = negotiations.where(main_member_id: 7)
  negotiations = negotiations.where(
    '((business_rank = ? and max_status = ?) or (business_rank = ? and max_status = ?) or (business_rank = ? and max_status = ?)) is false',
    'application', Supplier::Building::STATUS_APPLY,
    'agreement', Supplier::Building::STATUS_CONTRACT,
    'settlement', Supplier::Building::STATUS_SETTLEMENT
  )
```

Comment: hi, I have updated my question to provide class.And there are typo in the sample code like in "business_rank" it should be "n.business_rank"

Comment: can you break it down ? all I got is error from running the above code.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: Looks like the error somewhere outside of the code I provided. A quick proof https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/18fQ - executes fine.

Comment: is there a way to write this in a more readable rails/ruby way? I'm sorry for asking too much , I will accept the answer if we can't do anything about it.

Comment: I tried revising the above ssql because my requirements changed a little.

Comment: Added an example of more Rails/OOP way (you can change it according to your requirements if I misunderstood something).

Comment: sorry for demanding too much, but I prefer without using arel for version up purposes.. can we just use rails code? I'm really ok with not oop approach. If anything putting it in one method is my goal.

Comment: Sure we can, it's almost the same as the raw sql I showed. See updated example.